# tab y identacion se ve rojo neovim solo en python

Tags: python, configuración, vim

hace un tiempo uso neovim, nunca instale muchos pluggins ni nada pero hace poco decidí usar una configuración que encontré en github llamada [Optixal](https://github.com/Optixal/neovim-init.vim), la cosa es que cuando programo en c++ o js funciona perfecto pero cuando programo en python los espacios se ponen rojos y no se porque es, la verdad me gustaria que se vea como en la foto de react js

Python:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

js con react:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el archivo de configuración aunque es un poco grande

```
""" Optixal's Neovim Init.vim

""" Vim-Plug
call plug#begin()

" Aesthetics - Main
Plug 'dracula/vim', { 'commit': '147f389f4275cec4ef43ebc25e2011c57b45cc00' }
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
Plug 'junegunn/goyo.vim'
Plug 'junegunn/limelight.vim'
Plug 'junegunn/seoul256.vim'
Plug 'junegunn/vim-journal'
Plug 'junegunn/rainbow_parentheses.vim'
Plug 'nightsense/forgotten'
Plug 'zaki/zazen'

" Aethetics - Additional
Plug 'nightsense/nemo'
Plug 'yuttie/hydrangea-vim'
Plug 'chriskempson/tomorrow-theme', { 'rtp': 'vim' }
Plug 'rhysd/vim-color-spring-night'

" Functionalities
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plug 'majutsushi/tagbar'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plug 'Shougo/deoplete.nvim', { 'do': ':UpdateRemotePlugins' }
Plug 'deoplete-plugins/deoplete-jedi'
Plug 'ervandew/supertab'
Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Plug 'junegunn/vim-easy-align'
Plug 'alvan/vim-closetag'
Plug 'tpope/vim-abolish'
Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install() } }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plug 'chrisbra/Colorizer'
Plug 'KabbAmine/vCoolor.vim'
Plug 'heavenshell/vim-pydocstring', { 'do': 'make install' }
Plug 'vim-scripts/loremipsum'
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'
Plug 'metakirby5/codi.vim'
Plug 'dkarter/bullets.vim'

" Entertainment
"Plug 'ryanss/vim-hackernews'

call plug#end()

""" Python3 VirtualEnv
let g:python3_host_prog = expand('~/.config/nvim/env/bin/python')

""" Coloring
syntax on
color dracula
highlight Pmenu guibg=white guifg=black gui=bold
highlight Comment gui=bold
highlight Normal gui=none
highlight NonText guibg=none

" Opaque Background (Comment out to use terminal's profile)
set termguicolors

" Transparent Background (For i3 and compton)
highlight Normal guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE
highlight LineNr guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE

""" Other Configurations
filetype plugin indent on
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab smarttab autoindent
set incsearch ignorecase smartcase hlsearch
set ruler laststatus=2 showcmd showmode
set list listchars=trail:»,tab:»-
set fillchars+=vert:\ 
set wrap breakindent
set encoding=utf-8
set number
set title

""" Plugin Configurations

" NERDTree
let NERDTreeShowHidden=1
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable = '↠'
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible = '↡'

" Airline
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline_section_z = ' %{strftime("%-I:%M %p")}'
let g:airline_section_warning = ''
"let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1

" Neovim :Terminal
tmap <Esc> <C-\><C-n>
tmap <C-w> <Esc><C-w>
"tmap <C-d> <Esc>:q<CR>
autocmd BufWinEnter,WinEnter term://* startinsert
autocmd BufLeave term://* stopinsert

" Deoplete
let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1
" Disable documentation window
set completeopt-=preview

" vim-pydocstring
let g:pydocstring_doq_path = '~/.config/nvim/env/bin/doq'

" Supertab
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "<C-n>"

" Ultisnips
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<C-Space>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<Tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<C-x>"

" EasyAlign
xmap ga <Plug>(EasyAlign)
nmap ga <Plug>(EasyAlign)

" indentLine
let g:indentLine_char = '▏'
let g:indentLine_color_gui = '#363949'

" TagBar
let g:tagbar_width = 30
let g:tagbar_iconchars = ['↠', '↡']

" fzf-vim
let g:fzf_action = {
  \ 'ctrl-t': 'tab split',
  \ 'ctrl-s': 'split',
  \ 'ctrl-v': 'vsplit' }
let g:fzf_colors =
\ { 'fg':      ['fg', 'Normal'],
  \ 'bg':      ['bg', 'Normal'],
  \ 'hl':      ['fg', 'Comment'],
  \ 'fg+':     ['fg', 'CursorLine', 'CursorColumn', 'Normal'],
  \ 'bg+':     ['bg', 'CursorLine', 'CursorColumn'],
  \ 'hl+':     ['fg', 'Statement'],
  \ 'info':    ['fg', 'Type'],
  \ 'border':  ['fg', 'Ignore'],
  \ 'prompt':  ['fg', 'Character'],
  \ 'pointer': ['fg', 'Exception'],
  \ 'marker':  ['fg', 'Keyword'],
  \ 'spinner': ['fg', 'Label'],
  \ 'header':  ['fg', 'Comment'] }

""" Filetype-Specific Configurations

" HTML, XML, Jinja
autocmd FileType html setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 softtabstop=2
autocmd FileType css setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 softtabstop=2
autocmd FileType xml setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 softtabstop=2
autocmd FileType htmldjango setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 softtabstop=2
autocmd FileType htmldjango inoremap {{ {{  }}<left><left><left>
autocmd FileType htmldjango inoremap {% {%  %}<left><left><left>
autocmd FileType htmldjango inoremap {# {#  #}<left><left><left>

" Markdown and Journal
autocmd FileType markdown setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 softtabstop=2
autocmd FileType journal setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 softtabstop=2

""" Custom Functions

" Trim Whitespaces
function! TrimWhitespace()
    let l:save = winsaveview()
    %s/\\\@<!\s\+$//e
    call winrestview(l:save)
endfunction

" Dracula Mode (Dark)
function! ColorDracula()
    let g:airline_theme=''
    color dracula
    IndentLinesEnable
endfunction

" Seoul256 Mode (Dark & Light)
function! ColorSeoul256()
    let g:airline_theme='silver'
    color seoul256
    IndentLinesDisable
endfunction

" Forgotten Mode (Light)
function! ColorForgotten()
    " Light airline themes: tomorrow, silver, alduin
    " Light colors: forgotten-light, nemo-light
    let g:airline_theme='tomorrow'
    color forgotten-light
    IndentLinesDisable
endfunction

" Zazen Mode (Black & White)
function! ColorZazen()
    let g:airline_theme='badcat'
    color zazen
    IndentLinesEnable
endfunction

""" Custom Mappings

let mapleader=","
nmap <leader>q :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nmap \ <leader>q
nmap <leader>w :TagbarToggle<CR>
nmap <leader>ee :Colors<CR>
nmap <leader>ea :AirlineTheme 
nmap <leader>e1 :call ColorDracula()<CR>
nmap <leader>e2 :call ColorSeoul256()<CR>
nmap <leader>e3 :call ColorForgotten()<CR>
nmap <leader>e4 :call ColorZazen()<CR>
nmap <leader>r :so ~/.config/nvim/init.vim<CR>
nmap <leader>t :call TrimWhitespace()<CR>
xmap <leader>a gaip*
nmap <leader>a gaip*
nmap <leader>s <C-w>s<C-w>j:terminal<CR>
nmap <leader>vs <C-w>v<C-w>l:terminal<CR>
nmap <leader>d <Plug>(pydocstring)
nmap <leader>f :Files<CR>
nmap <leader>g :Goyo<CR>
nmap <leader>h :RainbowParentheses!!<CR>
nmap <leader>j :set filetype=journal<CR>
nmap <leader>k :ColorToggle<CR>
nmap <leader>l :Limelight!!<CR>
xmap <leader>l :Limelight!!<CR>
autocmd FileType python nmap <leader>x :0,$!~/.config/nvim/env/bin/python -m yapf<CR>
"nmap <leader>n :HackerNews best<CR>J
nmap <silent> <leader><leader> :noh<CR>
nmap <Tab> :bnext<CR>
nmap <S-Tab> :bprevious<CR>
```

Comment: Supongo que sólo te colorea de rojo los llamados _trailing spaces_, que serían los que aparecen al final de la línea y por tanto "sobran". Los marca en rojo para que los veas bien y los elimines. Optixal tiene el atajo `,t` para eliminarlos todos.